# JAXB serialization: Option to have a reference to inner objects

Tags: serialization, jaxb

We are serializing a large number of objects. Some objects have attributes as list of objects.

I found an option in Texo serializer where such list of objects are saved as references and a lot of space is saved rather than showing same object multiple times. eg shown below:

```
<target:LogicalFact id="6022" version="28"
created="2014-12-01T15:53:59.000+0000"       
logicalColumns="#/16651 #/10549 #/17142 #/16898 #/16542 #/16551 #/16832 #/16623 #/17230 #/16645 #/16393 #/16968 #/16575 #/17179 #/17195 #/16717 #/16636 #/16560 #/16410 #/16814 #/16610 #/16691 #/17173 #/16705 #/16838"/>
```

In above example, all logical columns are references. This saves space by avoiding duplicate information. Is there any such option available with JAXB serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably interested in `@XmlID`and `@XmlIDREF` which allow to reference objects.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlIDREF
    private Employee manager;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlList
    private List<Employee> reports;

    public Employee() {
        reports = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

}
```

Please see this the following post by Blaise Doughan:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

The code snippet above is taken from this post.